# Table model overflow

Tags: java, swing, jtable, buffer-overflow

I am adding around .25 million rows from access database to jtable, but table model is overflowing.

i am getting this error

"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Comment: Don't add that many rows to your JTable. No one can view that many rows, so having them in the model makes no sense. Cache/page your data in some sensible way.

Comment: but i need to display that many rows

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. The real issue is why you think that you need to display so many rows all at once, when the user can only see 50 at a time at most.

Comment: it is the requirement of the problem statement

Comment: Then add more memory to your computer and to your JVM heap

Comment: cant we use multiple table models and then append the data??